# Google Integration Test with REST API

Tags: google-api-java-client

I am trying to write some integration tests for my team's REST api. The application is integrated with google, and I want to make sure that sign in, sign up, account linking, etc, works properly from a backend perspective. As such, I am trying to write some integration tests. I can't seem to find anything within the google developer docs that illustrate a way I can approach logging in to Google without leveraging some front end resource. Is there a way I can achieve my goals?